# SmartBulbs.forEach Rendering Issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying to use excel.js and trying to loop through my dummy data originally contained in an excel column. When i try to loop through following a guide here for reference: https://medium.com/geekculture/exporting-data-in-excel-file-in-node-js-f1b298997d47

Only the header is rendering.

my code:

```js
const smartBulbs = require("../models/smartBulbs"); // This has data to be used
const excelJS = require("exceljs");

/**
 * @description Here we create a workbook. Inside the workbook, we create a worksheet.
 * Every sheet holds a different set of data. We download using the below command.
 * This will download in xlsx format. exceljs also provide a facility to download in CSV format
 * @param {*} req 
 * @param {*} res 
 */
const exportSmartBulbs = async (req, res) => { 
  const workbook = new excelJS.Workbook();  // Create a new workbook
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Smart Bulbs"); // New Worksheet
  const path = "./files";  // Path to download excel
  // Column for data in excel. key must match data key
  worksheet.columns = [
    { header: "Data Point (DP)", key: "dataPoint", width: 10 }
];
// Looping through data
let counter = 1;

  smartBulbs.forEach((bulbs) => {
  bulbs.dataPoint = counter;
  worksheet.addRow(bulbs.dataPoint); // Add data in worksheet
  counter++;
});
// Making first line in excel bold
worksheet.getRow(1).eachCell((cell) => {
  cell.font = { bold: true };
});
try {
  res.setHeader(
    "Content-Type",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  );
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename=smartbulbs.xlsx`);

  return workbook.xlsx.write(res).then(() => {
    res.status(200);
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({
    status: "error",
    message: "Something went wrong",
  });
  }
};

module.exports = exportSmartBulbs;
```

my model containing dummy data called in the code above:

```
const smartBulbs = [{
    dataPoint: 'Switch',
  },

  {
    dataPoint: 'Mode',
  },

  {
    dataPoint: 'Brightness-v1',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Color Temp',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Color',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Color',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Scene',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Scene',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Flash Scene1',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Flash Scene2',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Flash Scene3',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Flash Scene4',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Timer',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'MusicSync',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Real-TimeAdjustment',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'Gamma Debug',
  },
  {
    dataPoint: 'PowerOffMemory',
  }
];

module.exports = smartBulbs
```

Comment: What does `console.log(SmartBulbs)` show?

Comment: Might be a little too easy, but is it because you write `SmartBulbs` with lower case `s` in your model and then use it with upper case `S`?

Comment: @ahuemmer Thank you for pointing that out. I was playing around with the code and forgot to set that back. just edited my post.

Comment: after some updates to the code above i am getting the path to download. However, only the Header is rendering.

Comment: @cosmicslop This bears all the hallmarks of a chameleon question. The idea here is that you ask a specific question and you get a specific answer that is either correct or incorrect. By changing your question, you render the previous answers incorrect, invalidating the efforts of those who choose to help.

Comment: @spender Thank you. I am new to this but I hear what your'e saying. My Issue with my loop is more general now. Should I rephrase my post then?

Answer (score 0):

You are not exporting correctly.

`require` looks for the `exports` (with an `s`) property of the module.

Therefore it should be

```
module.exports = something
```

**NOT**

```
module.export = something
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, not sure how I missed that. updated my post. Now just getting dataPoint is not defined

Comment: if your error is referring to `smartBulbs.dataPoint = counter;`, `smartBulbs` is an array; each element has an object containing a `dataPoint` key, but the array doesn't have `dataPoint` as a direct child.

Comment: @user1599011 Thank you. Would you mind elaborating a little more?

Comment: Looking closer, you've overwritten `smartBulbs` in `smartBulbs.forEach((smartBulbs) => {
  smartBulbs.dataPoint = counter;
  worksheet.addRow(smartBulbs.dataPoint); // Add data in worksheet
  counter++;});`. Don't use `smartBulbs` as your array item; try something like `bulb` as in `smartBulbs.forEach((bulb) => {
bulb.dataPoint = counter;
  worksheet.addRow(bulb.dataPoint); // Add data in worksheet
  counter++;});`

Comment: @user1599011  thank you i'll be updating my post to reflect. However after running it still only renders the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the spread operator to convert your object to an array.

```
[...smartBulbs].foreach();
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. However it still only renders the Header of the column